# SQL alternative for GROUP BY or DISTINCT leading to performance issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a table filled with contact data:

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | email1 |
| 2 | email2 |
| 3 | email2 |
| 4 | email1 |
| 5 | email2 |

The output should not contain any duplicate emails. Desired output:

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | email1 |
| 2 | email2 |

I know this could easily be achived with DISTINCT or GROUP BY but they are not usable in my case.

I have figured out a working solution using NOT EXISTS but it gets extremely slow with a bunch of records (it takes already 5 seconds with 100 records):

```
SELECT * FROM contacts a WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM contacts b WHERE a.id > b.id AND a.email = b.email
);
```

Is there a way to improve that query regarding the performance or a simply a better approach as an alternative to DISTINCT or GROUP BY?

Comment: Make sure there's an index on `(id, email)`. It should become pretty fast. Also, `LIMIT 1` is not needed; remove it.

Comment: *Is there a way to improve that query regarding the performance* Yes. Create suitable index.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think that backward columns ordering is more safe.

Comment: @Akina I can't make my mind up about that. MySQL uses B+Tree indexes (that are double linked) and those can be traversed forward and backward with ease. Do you know about any documentation that can explain the need for reverse indexes?

Comment: @TheImpaler I know that "equal to" is performed more fast that "greater than". So the column which is used in the condition "equal" must be placed first in most cases.

Comment: @Akina Yes, you are absolutely right. I misread your comment. Thank you.

Comment: If there are there no other columns in those tables,

    SELECT MIN(id), email FROM t GROUP BY email

If there are more columns, what do you want them to be set to?

Do you really need the same `id`?

In other words, you must elaborate on "not usable in my case".

Comment: Get rid of the `LIMIT 1` in the EXISTS; it stops at the first match anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you should delete the dups??  (Hint: There is a better way than by using `DELETE`.)

Comment: There is no inherent reason why NOT EXISTS shouldn't perform.

Comment: What is the data type of `email`? a very long string? are there really only 2 column in this table? Please supply the DDL of that table (include all indexes).

Answer (score 1):

Based from your command, a "WHERE NOT EXISTS" is slow as its 1.) implying 2 SELECT commands, and 2.) has another WHERE condition just to make your desirable output a unique one.

The command, though working as a moment, is sadly inefficient in long term as your database grows into more data or rows.

Aside from indexing, as others suggested, you can also finetune your query by adjusting other resources like RAM or Disk Space - give or take you're working on the cloud environment like AWS or Azure.